# Progress on jQuery 3 $.when with multiple deferreds

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, jquery-3

In jQuery 3 (see [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2710)) it looks like `progress` on `$.when` changed behaviour. I'm looking to get a progress notification when each of my deferreds is resolved:

```js
var urls = [
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/2',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/1'
];
console.log('started');
var deferreds = $.map(urls, function(url) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET'
  })
  .always(function(){
    console.log('done %o', url)
    d.notify();
    d.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
  });
  return d.promise();
});

$.when.apply(jQuery, deferreds).progress(function(){
  // Does not call
  console.log('progress?');
}).done(function(){
  console.log('all done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code also on [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexlouden/pen/NdPdPY?editors=0011). Current output:

> "started"
>   "done https://httpbin.org/delay/1"
>   "done https://httpbin.org/delay/2"
>   "all done"

I'd expect to see a `progress?` output after each completed request.

Is there a nice way with the current jQuery API to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Allowing component promises to notify an aggregated promise :

- is not completely rational,
- was most probably a little used feature in jQuery 1 and 2 given that it never worked properly.

Consider:

```
var urls = [
    'https://httpbin.org/delay/2',
    'https://httpbin.org/delay/1'
];
console.clear();
console.log('started');
var promises = urls.map(function(url, i) {
    return $.Deferred(function(d) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET'
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log('done', i, url);
            d.notify(i);
            d.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
        });
    }).promise();
});

$.when.apply(null, promises).progress(function(x) {
    console.log('progress ' + x);
}).done(function() {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

In jQuery 1 or 2, you would reasonably expect :

> "started"
>   "done 1 https://httpbin.org/delay/1"
>   "progress 1"
>   "done 0 https://httpbin.org/delay/2"
>   "progress 0"
>   "all done"

But I get :

> "started"
>   "done 1 https://httpbin.org/delay/1"
>   "progress undefined"
>   "done 0 https://httpbin.org/delay/2"
>   "progress 0"
>   "all done"

Heaven only knows where that `undefined` came from.

Now try swapping the order of the two urls - I get :

> "started"
>   "done 0 https://httpbin.org/delay/1"
>   "progress 0"
>   "done 1 https://httpbin.org/delay/2"
>   "progress 0"
>   "all done"

Still not as expected - now you get "progress 0" twice!

IMHO, it's no great surprise that this feature was dropped in jQuery 3.

Comment: Ah interesting, I didn't know it was broken previously. Do you know of a way to get a function call when each component promise is resolved/notified? I'm less interested in the argument (0 or undefined is fine!) and more hoping for a nice way to keep track of the progress of all my concurrent requests.

Comment: I wonder if you really want `notify()`/`progress()`, which are to do with intermediate events while a promise is still pending. If you want to observe the success/failure of the individual ajax calls, then you are already doing so with `console.log()` in the `.always()` handler. Of course, you can do more than `console.log()`, for example give the user a progress bar or message to indicate how many of the individual ajax calls have fulfilled/failed, but that's nothing to do with `.notify()`/`.progress()`.

Comment: I was hoping for a nice way to separate the ajax calls and handling of progress, but I ended up putting the progress logic into `.always()` - thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with following code:

```js
var urls = [
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/2',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/1'
];

console.log('started');
var deferreds = $.map(urls, function(url) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(){
      d.notify(); //notify the progress handler about the current progress
    } 
  })
  .always(function(){
    console.log('done %o', url)
    d.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
  });
  return d.promise();
});

$.when.apply(jQuery, deferreds).progress(function(){
  // Does not call
  console.log('progress?');
}).done(function(){
  console.log('all done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Here we have added the `success` handler for `ajax` via which we are calling the [deferred.notify()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/) by which [progress](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) will get called

Comment: `.success` isn't a valid function, but if I use `.done` or put it in `.always` (above the `d.resolve`) then I still get the same result, `.progress` doesn't get called

Comment: oh...sorry for that. `success` has to be part of options passed to `ajax` setup. You are correct.

Comment: No worries! Same result I'm afraid - calling `d.notify` doesn't help (whether from a `success` callback or from a deferred `.always`). I think it's related to the changes in jQuery in 3.0 - see the issue I linked above.

Comment: I'm using `.always` because I'd like the `$.when` `.done` function to call after all the requests complete (either succeed or fail).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm using jQuery 3 (see the tag), switching to 1 isn't an option

Comment: could you please check this snippet. I guess its working as per your requirement. I can see `progress?` before each `done`.

Comment: oh I see. Issue with version JQ 3.0

Comment: Yeah agreed, thanks for your help though! I was just wondering if there was an easy way to achieve the same thing with jquery 3!

Comment: the simplest way will be to call `console.log('progress?');` or required function at the place of `d.notify();`